# Create a wireless network while connected to another

Tags: wifi, ad-hoc

I am looking for something like the `hostednetwork` on Windows, which lets you create a wireless connection at the same time as being connected to another.

I have a widespread enterprise wireless network, which, for security reasons, blocks all communication between devices on the network. However, in order to test mobile websites and such, I need my devices to connect to my MacBook Air.

I can create a wireless network from the Wi-Fi menu, but that knocks me off the main wireless connection, so both my MacBook and my iPod have no internet. I used to be able to create a second wireless ad-hoc network in Windows that my devices could connect to, while my laptop would remain connected to the main wireless network, but I am unable to find a similar option in Mac.

Is there any such feature in mac at all? If so, how can I use it?

I am not against using the Terminal. Also, feel free to migrate to SuperUser if this may be a better fit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, [not possible](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=36706) with Mac.

Comment: That guy is talking about simultaneously connecting to two wireless networks. I want to connect to one, and create the other. Windows can't join two at the same time either.